# How to solve namespaces problems in php tinker?

Tags: php, namespaces, tinker

I have the following code:

```
<?php
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
class Enemy extends Model
{
    // ...
    static function fight($id)
    {
        if(Enemy::calcDist($id))
        {
            $model = Enemy::find($id);
            if($model->status == 1)
            {
                $model->status = 2;
                $model->save();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I try to do `App\Enemy::fight(1)` in php tinker it shows error:

`"Class 'App\App\Enemy' not found"`.

I tried with `"calcDist($id)"`, with `"self::calcDist($id)"`, also at `find($id)` function, but no result.

How I can solve this?

Edit: I found the problem; that error comes from another part of code...

Comment: Don't pollute `App`, put models in  their own `namespace App\Model;`, then call `Model\Enemy::fight($id)` or add use, which makes more sense.

Comment: Artisan decided that place, and I have to keep it for project sharing.

Answer (score 1):

When you are in `namespace App` you dont need to use `App\Enemy` in your call.

Simply use `Enemy::fight(1)`, or use the absolute namespace `\App\Enemy::fight(1)`

When you use a static class by his name, the engine search the class into the current namespace. If no namespace is given, then it uses the namespace "\".

```
namespace App;

Enemy::fight(1); // \App\Enemy::fight(1) ok
App\Enemy::fight(1); // \App\App\Enemy::fight(1) wrong
```

Comment: Try using the absolute class path `\App\Enemy::fight(1)`. Are you sure the error is from this line?

Comment: Same thing. I also tried "App\Enemy::add(...)", another function from that class that not have any functions from Enemy class inside, and it works.

Comment: Could you update your post with the code section (or the important part) where you called the fight() method, including  namespace declarations?

Comment: I'm calling that function in "php artisan tinker" in my project root, as an single line. I also tried change namespace.